# sqldeveloper update set commit does not work

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I would like to update a value in a table using:

```
update TABLE_NAME set col_name = 'abc' WHERE ID = '12345' ;
commit;
```

The output returned "Commit complete" but nothing is changed as I tried to verify in the table. The issue remains even if I reopen sqldeveloper. Why is this happening and how can I fix it? Thx

---

Sorry there was a typo, it was "update TABLE_NAME ... " instead of "update col_value ..."

Comment: What does the message for the update is it `0 rows updated`?. May the bcoz of `WHERE` condition no rows are matched to update.

Comment: Did you verify rows are affected by this update? Execute "SELECT col_name FROM col_value WHERE id = '12345'" first and check if results appear.  If I should guess, I assume that the id column is of type int, so quoting is incorrect.

Comment: Hi @JonasMetzler thanks for your reply, I checked using your code after committing my code and nothing changed.

Comment: Hi @KiranMarturu, there is a row attached to the ID as I could filter using ID = '12345'

Comment: Could you please add the create table command of your table to your question?

Comment: @JonasMetzler sorry I can't seem to find it, are you after the columns' data type?

Comment: I want try to replicate your issue. In common SQL Developers for Oracle, it should be possible to mark your table name in your query and then press CRLT and F4 or Shift and F4 to open the properties of your table. There you can see the information like the data type and it should also be possible to get the create table command there.

Comment: @JonasMetzler Yes I can see the columns , Constriants, Grant ... Could you please tell me which is the create table command?

Comment: This depends on your setup and exact tool and should not be discussed here. There are a lot of documentations in the net, as example http://dba.fyicenter.com/faq/oracle/Retrieve-CREATE-TABLE-Statement-with-SQL-Developer.html

Comment: Hi @JonasMetzler much appreciate your help. Just solved the issue with selecting the script and run(previously it didn't work if I just click the run button), I don't know why but it seemed to work :)